# Prove that there are no nontrivial cycles in any transitive, antisymmetric relation R.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

A cycle in a relation R is a sequence of k distinct elements a_0, a_1, ..., a_(k-1) of A where (a_i, a_((i+1) mod k)) ∈ R for each i ∈ {0, 1, ..., k-1}. A cycle is nontrivial if k ≥ 2. Prove that there are no nontrivial cycles in any transitive, antisymmetric relation R.

---

I understand that a cycle in graph theory is a path of length >= 2 from vertex u, back to vertex u that doesn't traverse the same edge twice. What I don't understand is how can I represent a cycle as a set of relations, and then prove that it holds the following properties? Thanks for your help.

---

I will prove by contrapositive and say that if R is transitive and has a non-trivial cycle, then R is not anti-symmetric.

To do this I will show that if (a_i, a_i+1) ∈ R for i = 0, 1, ..., k-2; then (a_0, a_k-1) ∈ R using induction on i.

Let i = j for some j ∈ Natural Numbers. The base case will be j=0 and thus we have,


(a_0, a_0) = (a_0, a_(0 (mod 1))) == (a_0, a_0)


Our inductions hypothesis will be to assume that (a_k-1, a_0) ∈ R.
Next we will assume that (a_0, a_j) is in the relation R, for some j ∈ {1,2,...,k-2} Thus,


(a_0, a_j+1) == (a_0, a_k-1)


Therefore, since (a_0, a_k-1) ∈ R, and (a_k-1, a_0) ∈ R by the I.H.; and since every node is different, a_0 =/= a_k-1, hence R cannot be anti-symmetric, hence proved. 


Q.E.D.

Comment: Is $(a_{k-1},a_0)$ an element of $R$?

Comment: No I don't think so because (a_i, a_((i+1) mod k))

Comment: @john123: That is precisely why $\langle a_{k-1},a_0\rangle$ **is** an element of $R$: $(k-1)+1\bmod{k}=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott if this graph is undirected then would that mean the ordered pair (a_(k-1), a_0) and (a_0, a_(k-1)) are the same? meaning that both of these pairs could not be in the relation?

Comment: @john123: The graph is directed: an ordered pair $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ corresponds to a directed edge from $x$ to $y$, while $\langle y,x\rangle\in R$ corresponds to a directed edge from $y$ to $x$. But really you don’t need to think about graphs at all: just accept that a cycle of length $k$ in $R$ is a set $\{a_0,\ldots,a_{k-1}\}$ of $k$ elements of $A$ such that $$a_0\,R\,a_1\,R\,\ldots\,R\,a_{k-1}\,R\,a_0\;.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott YES! this brings me to remember why we used mod in conways game of life to make the wrap around effect!

Comment: @john123: Yep; it’s a handy trick when you need a wrap-around.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi can you tell me how I am doing? Should I be doing induction from j = 1, 2, ..., k-1 instead?

Comment: @john123: You got off on the wrong foot. Your base case is that $\langle a_0,a_1\rangle\in R$, which is true by hypothesis. Your induction step should then be to suppose that $\langle a_0,a_i\rangle\in R$ for some $i\in\{1,\ldots,k-2\}$ and use that to prove that $\langle a_0,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$. If you can do that, the principle of mathematical induction will allow you to conclude that $\langle a_0,a_{k-1}\rangle\in R$. (This is an example of a finite mathematical induction: we go only up to $i=k-2$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hi, I believe I have concluded my statement. Would you double check my work? Thanks again.

Comment: @john123: You can’t start with $\langle a_0,a_0\rangle\in R$: there is absolutely no reason to think that this is even true. As I said, the base case is that $\langle a_0,a_{\color{red}1}\rangle\in R$. And I’m afraid that much of what you’ve written after that really doesn’t make sense, either notationally or as an induction argument. I need to get some dinner, but in a bit I’ll turn my hint answer into a full solution; I think that you’ve enough confusion about what’s going on that that would be a better use of our time and energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not a matter of representing a cycle as a set of relations: you’re dealing with only one relation. For example, consider a tiny round-robin tennis tournament in which $A$ beats $B$, $B$ beats $C$, and $C$ beats $A$. Then the relation $x\,r\,y$ iff $x$ beats $y$ in this tournament has a non-trivial cycle $A,B,C$: $A\,r\,B$, $B\,r\,C$, and $C\,r\,A$.

You’re asked to show that if a relation $R$ is transitive and antisymmetric, then it cannot have a non-trivial cycle. In other words, there cannot be elements $a_0,\ldots,a_{k-1}$ in the underlying set such that $k\ge 1$, $\langle a_i,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$ for $i=0,\ldots,k-2$, and $\langle a_{k-1},a_0\rangle\in R$.

HINT: Show that if $\langle a_i,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$ for $i=0,\ldots,k-2$, then $\langle a_0,a_{k-1}\rangle\in R$. I’ve added a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below; mouse over it to see it.

**Added:** We’ll assume that $R$ is transitive and has a cycle $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1}$ of length $k\ge 2$ and prove that $R$ cannot then be antisymmetric. From this it follows at once that a transitive, antisymmetric relation cannot have a non-trivial cycle.

We’ll begin by proving by induction on $i$ that $\langle a_0,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k-2$. To get the induction started, we know that this is true for $i=1$: $\langle a_0,a_1\rangle\in R$ by hypothesis. For the induction step we need to prove that if $\langle a_0,a_i\rangle\in R$ for some $i<k-2$, then $\langle a_0,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$. Since $i<k-2$, we know by hypothesis that $\langle a_i,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$, and the induction hypothesis tells us that $\langle a_0,a_i\rangle\in R$. We also know that $R$ is transitive, so $\langle a_0,a_{i+1}\rangle\in R$, which is exactly what we wanted. By induction, therefore, we can conclude that $\langle a_0,a_i\rangle\in R$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,a_{k-1}$, and in particular that $\langle a_0,a_{k-1}\rangle\in R$.

That concludes the induction part of the proof, and we now use that result. We have $\langle a_0,a_{k-1}\rangle\in R$ from the induction argument, and we know by hypothesis that $\langle a_{k-1},a_0\rangle\in R$. And by hypothesis $k\ge 2$, so $a_0\ne a_{k-1}$, so $R$ is not antisymmetric. This concludes the proof.

Comment: What do you mean when you say underlying set. Are you talking about a_i in A?

Comment: @john123: The relation $R$ is a set of ordered pairs. The set from which the elements of these pairs are drawn is its underlying set. You never gave it a name, so I was forced to describe it rather than name it, but if $A$ is your name for the set on which $R$ is a relation, then yes, I’m talking about $A$.

Comment: So in your example, the underlying set in which the ordered pairs are drawn from is {A, B, C} and k = 3?

Comment: @john123: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: @john123: I’m suggesting that you prove that if $R$ is transitive and has a non-trivial cycle, then it cannot be antisymmetric, which is one form of the contrapositive. What you wrote, though, is not and is not equivalent to the result that you’re being asked to prove.

Comment: if (a_0, a_1) is in R, does this imply that (a_1, a_0) is in R as well?

Comment: @john123: No: a relation $R$ on $A$ can be **any** subset of $A\times A$. For instance, $<$ is a relation on $\Bbb Z$; does $1<2$ imply that $2<1$? Clearly not. A relation $R$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ **does** imply that $\langle y,x\rangle\in R$ is called a *symmetric* relation.

Comment: Basically how can I show that R is not anti-symmetric.

Comment: @john123: What does it mean for $R$ to be antisymmetric? Whenever $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ **and** $\langle y,x\rangle\in R$, then ... what?

Comment: x == y.  So if I know that (a_0, a_k-1) and (a_k-1, a_0) are in the ordered pairs then it cannot be anti symmetric because no two nodes are equal.

Comment: @john123: There you go! Yes: if you can show that $\langle a_0,a_{k-1}\rangle\in R$, you can combine that with the hypothesis that $\langle a_{k-1},a_0\rangle\in R$ to conclude that $R$ is not antisymmetric.

Comment: Prof Scott, can you kindly help us, thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686268/for-any-sequence-of-real-numbers-one-can-always-find-a-subsequence-that-is-mono